# grails application redirects to previous DNS

Tags: grails, redirect

The admins here moved the grails application to a new subnet and changed the DNS. My application however continues to redirect and create links to the previous subnet/DNS. I searched my project for any use of the old DNS without any hits.

this is what the redirect logic looks like:

```
withFormat {
        // Browsers re-direct to prevent multi-submit issues, the others just get the data of the created Evaluation
        html {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'evaluation.label', default: 'Evaluation'), evaluationInstance.id])
            flash.messageType = "success"
            redirect(
                    mapping: "restChild",
                    params: [
                            parent:'performanceReview',
                            parentId: evaluationInstance.performanceReview.id,
                            id: evaluationInstance.id
                    ]
            )
        }
        json {
            response.status = 201
            response.setHeader("Location", createLink(mapping: "restEntity", absolute: true, id: evaluationInstance.id).toString())
            forward(action: "show", id: evaluationInstance.id)
        }
        xml {
            response.status = 201
            response.setHeader("Location", createLink(mapping: "restEntity", absolute: true, id: evaluationInstance.id).toString())
            forward(action: "show", id: evaluationInstance.id)
        }
    }
```

this is the conf/URLMappings.groovy file

```
// RESTful entity mapping
name restEntity: "/$controller/$id"(parseRequest: true) {
    action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update", POST: "update", DELETE: "delete"]
    constraints {
        id matches: /\d+/
    }
}
```

my question is, where would i look to fix the domain name for the redirects?

Comment: @Andrew that did it, could you post that as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically controlled by the `grails.serverURL` config setting in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` (or external config file)

The base URL value set in `grails.serverURL` is used when generating links in this way: `createLink(... absolute: true)`.  [Link to reference docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html).